# Reg Exp: Get string only if it is not between a tags

Tags: regex

I am doing a search and replace of some terms, adding a link to these words. If these words are already part of another link, I should avoid it the replace (if not, I should end with `<a href...> <a href ...> word </a> </a>`, which is something I want to avoid.

I don't know if this is possible, so I'd like to know that and if in case it is, any hint. I am kind of lost. So far, I am being able only to get those words that are part of a link, but not those which exclusively are not.

Thanks!

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: process the DOM. don't regex.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$urls = array('word1'=> 'http://urlfor.word1.com',
              'word2'=> 'http://urlfor.word2.com',
              'word3'=> 'http://urlfor.word3.com');

$pattern = '~<(?:a\s.*?</a>|!--.*?(?:-->|$)|[^>]+>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b~sD';

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($urls) {
    return '<a href="' . $urls[$m[0]] . '">' . $m[0] . '</a>'; },
    $html);
```

`$urls` is an associative array where keys are the words and the values are corresponding urls.

the pattern use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick to skip parts that are already between link tags, inside a tag or in an html comment. *(Note that you can easily extend the pattern to skip script, style and CDATA content or to deal with unclosed `<a>` tags )*

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

`~<(?:a\s.*?</a>|[^>]+>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?:ultrices)\b~ig`

adding g to get all the matches and not only the first one.

Comment: you need to [accept the answer which helped you the most](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).